# What is $\lim _{ x\to { 1 }^{ - } }{ \prod _{ n=0 }^{ \infty }{ { \left( \frac { 1+{ x }^{ n+1 } }{ 1+{ x }^{ n } } \right) }^{ { x }^{ n } } } }$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

$$\lim _{ x\rightarrow { 1 }^{ - } }{ \prod _{ n=0 }^{ \infty  }{ { \left( \frac { 1+{ x }^{ n+1 } }{ 1+{ x }^{ n } }  \right)  }^{ { x }^{ n } } }  } $$
I tried it as follow but not able to proceed further
$$L=\lim _{ x\rightarrow { 1 }^{ - } }{ \prod _{ n=0 }^{ \infty  }{ { \left( \frac { 1+{ x }^{ n+1 } }{ 1+{ x }^{ n } }  \right)  }^{ { x }^{ n } } }  } \\ \ln { L } =\lim _{ x\rightarrow { 1 }^{ - } }{ \sum _{ n=0 }^{ \infty  }{ \ln { { \left( \frac { 1+{ x }^{ n+1 } }{ 1+{ x }^{ n } }  \right)  }^{ { x }^{ n } } }  }  } \\ \ln { L } =\lim _{ x\rightarrow { 1 }^{ - } }{ { x }^{ n } } \sum _{ n=0 }^{ \infty  }{ \ln { { \left( 1+\frac { { x }^{ n }(x-1) }{ 1+{ x }^{ n } }  \right)  } }  } \\ \ln { L } \le \lim _{ x\rightarrow { 1 }^{ - } }{ (x-1)\left( \frac { { x }^{ 2 } }{ 1+x } +\frac { { x }^{ 4 } }{ { 1+x }^{ 2 } } +\frac { { x }^{ 6 } }{ { 1+x }^{ 3 } } +..... \right)  } $$

Comment: You cant pull $x^n$ out of the sum

Answer (score 1):

You made an error in the second step. You actually have that $$\ln L = \lim_{x \to 1^-} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\ln\left(1 + \frac{x^n(x-1)}{1+x^n} \right)$$

The sum is equivalent to $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^{n}\ln\left(\frac{1+x^{n+1}}{1+x^{n}}\right)=\lim_{N \to \infty} \sum_{n=0}^{N}x^{n}\ln\left(\frac{1+x^{n+1}}{1+x^{n}}\right)$$

By telescoping, the sum inside the limit is equal to $$x^{N}\left(\ln\left(1+x^{\left(N+1\right)}\right)\right)-x^{0}\ln\left(1+x^{0}\right)+\sum_{n=1}^{N}\left(x^{\left(n-1\right)}-x^{n}\right)\ln\left(1+x^{n}\right)$$

As $N \to \infty$ and $x \to 1^-$, this simplifies to $$-\ln\left(2\right)+\sum_{n=1}^{N}\left(x^{\left(n-1\right)}-x^{n}\right)\ln\left(1+x^{n}\right)$$

Using the series expansion of $\ln(1+x)$, this is equal to $$-\ln\left(2\right)+\sum_{n=1}^{N}\left(x^{\left(n-1\right)}-x^{n}\right)\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{\left(k+1\right)}}{k}x^{nk}$$

Changing the order of sums and then taking the limit as $N \to \infty$ yields $$-\ln\left(2\right)+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{\left(k+1\right)}}{k}\cdot\frac{\left(-1+x\right)x^{k}}{-1+x^{\left(1+k\right)}}$$

Since $$\lim_{x \to 1^-} \frac{\left(-1+x\right)x^{k}}{-1+x^{\left(1+k\right)}} = \frac{1}{1+k}$$, this simplifies to $$\ln L = -\ln\left(2\right)+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{\left(k+1\right)}}{k\left(k+1\right)}$$

By telescoping and knowing that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k}{k} = -\ln(2)$, this simplifies to $$\ln L = \ln(2)-1 \to L = \frac{2}{e}$$